# how solve this error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

i'm using "react with axios" to get data from fake API ( https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)
what i want from the code: when i press on a certain user, all user's information should appear to me , while this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" appear to me and i don't know what i do.

.........................
App.js
.........................

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Home from './component/Home/Home';
import About from './component/About/About';
import UsersPage from './component/UsersPage/UsersPage';
import UserPage from './component/UserPage/UserPage'

class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Fragment>
      <NavLink to='/'> Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to='/users'> Users</NavLink>
      <NavLink to='/About'> About</NavLink>

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />}  />
        <Route path='/About' exact element={<About />}  />
        <Route path='/users' exact element={<UsersPage />}  />
        <Route path='/users/:id' exact element={<UserPage />}  />
      </Routes>

    </Fragment>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
}
 export default App;
```

.........................
Users-axios.js
.........................

```
import axios from "axios";

export async function getUsers() {
  const response = await 
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response;
}

export async function getUser(id) {
  const respon = await 
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+id);
  return respon;
}
```

.........................
UsersPage.js
.........................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {getUsers} from '../../Api/Users-axios'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

export class UsersPage extends Component {
state = {
    users: []
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    getUsers().then(respo => {
        console.log(respo)
        this.setState({
            users: respo.data
        })
    })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('error mount');
        })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map(user =>
                    <li key={user.id}>
                        {user.name}{" "}
                        {user.id}
                        <NavLink to={"/users/" + user.id}>View</NavLink>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
   }
  }

 export default UsersPage;
```

.........................
UserPage.js
.........................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {getUser} from '../../Api/Users-axios'
import ViewUserComp from '../ViewUserComp/ViewUserComp'
import {useParams} from 'react-router'


export class UserPage extends Component {
 state = {
   user:{}
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this.props)     
    let {id} = useParams;
    console.log('my id:' );
    console.log(id);
    getUser(id).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            user: response.data
        });
    })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('error');
        });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <h2>User Page</h2>
        <ViewUserComp user={this.state.user} />     
    </div>
    )
  }
 }
export default UserPage;
```

...............................
ViewUserComp.js
...............................

```
import React from 'react'
  function ViewUserComp(props) {
   return (
    <div>
        <p>id: {props.user.id}</p>
        <p>Name: {props.user.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {props.user.email}</p>
    </div>
 )
}
export default ViewUserComp;
```

The error is clear as in the following image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the class component inside of **withRouter** since hooks won't work with class based components.

......................... UserPage.js .........................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {getUser} from '../../Api/Users-axios'
import ViewUserComp from '../ViewUserComp/ViewUserComp'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'


export class UserPage extends Component {
 state = {
   user:{}
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this.props)     
    const id = this.props.match.params.id; // try this one
    console.log('my id:' );
    console.log(id);
    getUser(id).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            user: response.data
        });
    })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('error');
        });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <h2>User Page</h2>
        <ViewUserComp user={this.state.user} />     
    </div>
    )
  }
 }
 export default withRouter(UserPage); // wrap it
```

Answer (score 0):

In hook, Use `useParams()`. Example like below.

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

let { id } = useParams();
```

Comment: when i use >> useParams() >> appear another error  >> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.